# Do I need to create folders for conversion in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

Suppose I want to convert:

```
http://localhost/profile/view?q=James
```

into

```
http://localhost/profile/view/James
```

The problem is I have to create a new folder called 'view' for this purpose. Is there a way so that I do not need to create a folder for this purpose? What is the htaccess rule for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't. You use `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess`. This effectively matches a regex against your URL and then transforms it however you tell it (much like: `preg_replace`).

```
RewriteRule ^profile/view/([\w]+)/?$ path/to/profile/file.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Then the user navigates to:

```
http://www.website.com/profile/view/john
```

and the server points the user to:

```
http://www.website.com/path/to/profile/file.php?q=john
```

Comment: Hi, can I do something like this: `RewriteRule ^http://localhost/profile/posts/([\w]+)/?$ http://localhost/profile/posts?name=$1 [L]`?

Comment: @AD-1 Yes, kind of and no, not really. It somewhat depends what you're trying to achieve? You, could for example use a `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ...` to get the URL and you could check whether `http or https` with a similar condition and then use a rewrite afterwards. But without knowing the input and intended output it's hard to say exactly

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like this http://localhost/profile/john/posts from http://localhost/profile/posts?name=john. Is this possible? P.S. thanks for helping.

Comment: @AD-1 Can you explain the directory structure? (i.e. where the end point file is)

Comment: @AD-1 but probably you want something like: `RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)/posts$ profile/posts.php?name=$1`

Comment: @AD-1 yes, it's possible